# Window load function in PHP

Tags: jquery

I have a php file called abc.php.I am trying to call fadeOut function of jquery at onload of abc.php file.but it seems that its not even calling jquery $(window).load(function() after page loading.Can anyone help ??my abc.php file looks like this :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
$("#pageloaddiv1").fadeOut(2000);
});
</script>
<div id="pageloaddiv1"></div>


 <?php
  //php code
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: There's nothing in the DIV, so how can you tell that it's not fading out?

Comment: .load is for external scripts. You may be thinking of $(document).ready()

Comment: Have you tried putting a console.log or alert statement in the window.load callback?

Comment: it might be empty just to illustrate that it exists

Comment: @KaiQing `.load()` is also an event handler, it's equivalent to `window.onload = function()`.

Comment: It works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/VnE5w/ PHP is irrelevant to this.

Comment: @barmer I have define a css in DIV #pageloaddiv1 {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
background: url('./images/pageloader.gif') no-repeat center center;
}

Comment: Check your Javascript console for errors.

Comment: I updated that fiddle with your CSS and it works just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/VnE5w/1/

Comment: @Jay and barmer : it is working for html files but here I have a .php file :(

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is PHP or HTML, the browser renders it the same way, as HTML. Unless your PHP isn't parsing, in which case you have a server issue, not a jQuery problem.

Comment: I just tried with document.ready and its working .thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the **ready** event instead of **load** and use **$(document)** better

Comment: This would be better as a comment to the OP as this is not an answer.